# Is there a MySQL version of Oracle's %TYPE

Tags: mysql, oracle, types

In Oracle, if I needed to declare something with the same type as another column, I can simply use `%type`:

```sql
Create table foo(
   copiedType OTHER_TABLE.COLUMN_NAME%TYPE
   /* yada yada yada... */
```

Is there an equivalent operator in MySQL?

Comment: I don't think that is possible in MySQL.

Comment: @EmmanuelN Yea... I didn't think so. You know, Oracle is not perfect, but it has a couple of niceties that MySQL lacks. (That said, PostGreSQL is the best of both world, but I am in love with that DB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the short answer, as it turns out is "no", and while it *can* be faked if you're willing to create a stored function (or use another language) and create your table by your own custom baked parsing engine, it simply isn't worth it. C'est sera...

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something the only alternative to the Oracle `%type` in MySQL is the following,

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'col_name';
```

Comment: Which I'm pretty sure you can't use within a `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: @Dennis I know how to get a column type, but because I simply don't want to have to think about schema integrity (thinking is dangerous), I would prefer to have something I can use in a variable declaration or column definition.

Comment: @cwallenpoole Understandable. In theory you should be able to create a procedure which stores the above output into a variable & then uses said variable to create the table you are attempting to construct. I have not tried this though so could not say for sure that it would work.